# JXL gerar planilha excel com valor decimal no padrão brasileiro

Tags: java, jsf, microsoft-excel

Estou usando Java e Jsf em meu sistema e há uma tela onde tem a opção de gerar uma planilha excel. A geração da planilha está ok. O problema que estou encontrando é nas colunas que possuem valores numéricos do tipo Double. Por exemplo:

[image: tabela gerada com o jxl]

Reparem que os valores das duas colunas são gerados no padrão americano com um ponto de casa decimal ao invés de vírgula. Dessa forma quando o usuário vai aproveitar a planilha para criar uma fórmula e somar os valores o excel não aceita, pois esse padrão de formatação de número não é o BR.

Tentei formatar os valores para o padrão BR usando a classe NumberFormat vejam:
[image: Planilha com valores formatados]

Só que não sei pq diabos ao imprimir o número o jxl coloca ' antes do número. Isso continua impedindo o usuário de criar uma fórmula para somar as células, pois como tem essa ' antes do número o excel o enxerga como String e não soma. Vejam na imagem abaixo o ' que é imprimido antes do número:

[image: Apóstrofe sendo imprimida antes do valor formatado]

Alguém já passou por isso? Como posso imprimir o valor no padrão BR para que o usuário que gerou a planilha possa criar fórmulas para somar as células? Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver. Vou postar a solução no caso de alguém encontrar o mesmo problema:

```html
NumberFormat decimalNo = new NumberFormat("#,##0.00");
WritableCellFormat numberFormat = new WritableCellFormat(decimalNo);

planilha.addCell(new Number(col++, row, ((Double) item).doubleValue(), numberFormat));
```